# Why am I getting a "bad file descriptor" error when syncing file in rust?

Tags: rust

Sometimes I get `Bad file descriptor (os error 9)` with following code

```
let mut f = fs::File::create(new_path.as_path()).expect("Could not save new file.");
f.write_all(buf).expect("Could not write buffer to file.");
f.sync_all().expect("Could not sync file I/O.");
```

It is observed that the error happen only with `sync_all`, which is quite confusing to me. If the file descriptor is bad, why there is no error triggered with `write_all()`?

Furthermore, after the error happens, I can observe that the file actually is written successfully with correct content and metadata.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @kmdreko this is the OS info: `Linux 5.4.0-104-generic #118~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 3 13:53:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The rust version: `rustc 1.57.0`

Comment: Does the program do other things in other threads while this is running? Is it calling into foreign (C) code?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, there are some other threads and processes reading/writing files. Is it possible that they pollute the fd? Yes, there is C code called sometimes, but they do not read/write files.

Comment: In general, this smells like the file is getting closed after the write but before the sync. Using `strace` or a similar syscall-level tracing tool (I'm personally fond of `sysdig`, but tools like `ebpftrace` are very well-suited too) would let you confirm this.

Comment: ...a [mre] that let others reliably see the problem themselves would be very helpful -- it's much easier to speak definitively to what's happening in a problem one can reproduce and trace.

Comment: hmm, after I add a `RwLock` for all file read/write, the problem temporally disappears. But it is still confusing, that file is only written by that thread/process, no other code will read/write it.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is closed when the execution is switched to other threads/processes, and then the sync becomes error when the execution is switched back?